# How to make JNLP download the correct version of JavaFX 2?

Tags: java, cross-platform, 32bit-64bit, jnlp, javafx-2

JavaFX 2 is highly dependent on native code.
For my desktop application, I would like to select the best-matching JavaFX flavor for each supported OS to make the installation on the target systems as painless as possible.

Since JavaFX 2 comes with several Ant tasks to help with deployment, I thought this was the way to go, but I seem to have hit a dead end.

The `deploy` task generates a JNLP file which includes a resource reference that calls the JavaFX installer:

```
 <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.1+" ref="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
 </resources>
```

This obviously won't work on OSs other than Windows, possibly even 32-bit Windows.
According to the [JNLP doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources), OS-dependent resource selection is possible, though:

```
<resources os="SunOS" arch="sparc">
   ...
</resources>
```

However, I can't figure out the URLs for the different platforms. Are they documented somewhere? Is there another way to reach my goal?

Please note that there already is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176237/how-to-deploy-a-desktop-javafx-2-0-application-correctly-using-jnlp-for-32-and-6), but it limits itself to the 32/64-bit part of the issue and goes unanswered at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jnlp and plugin modes are supported only on Windows in current JavaFX 2.1

Mac/Linux runtime is planned to be added in 2.2 release. You can try development preview bundles: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html

Comment: Thanks, Sergey. Do you know whether the kenai-jira has issues for this that I could watch?

Comment: Sure: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-21284 `JNLP installer need to support Linux/Mac`